# How can I speed up this code with multiple sum？

Tags: summation

There are 4 variables in this multiple sum, therefore it may take a long time.   I have run this program for *12 hours*, but no result untill now.  I want to know how to speed up this code.  Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated!

the code is bellow:

```
data = Table[Exp[-((i + j - 100.)/10)^2] Exp[-((i - j)/10)^2], {i, 100}, {j, 100}];
data = Chop[data, 0.00001];
data = data/Sqrt[Sum[(data[[i, j]])^2, {i, 1, 100}, {j, 1, 100}]];
ListDensityPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0, Mesh -> All, 
 PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Hue[2/3], Hue[0]}, #] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
S1[i_, j_, k_, m_, 
   t_] := (data[[i, k]] data[[j, m]])^2 + (data[[j, k]] data[[i, 
       m]])^2 - 
   2 data[[i, k]] data[[j, m]] data[[j, k]] data[[i, 
      m]] Cos[(2 \[Pi]*(3*10^8)/(1584 - 5 + j*0.1 - 0.05) - 
        2 \[Pi]*(3*10^8)/(1584 - 5 + i*0.1 - 0.05)) t];
S2[t_] := 1/4*\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(100\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(100\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k = 1\), \(100\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(m = 1\), \(100\)]S1[i, j, k, m, t]\)\)\)\);
ListPlot[Table[S2[i], {i, -0.01, 0.01, 0.0001}], Joined -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

Comment: I _guess_ you could speed up your code by using `SparseArray` and `ParallelSum`.

Comment: I'd suggest precomputing `S1` and `S2`, instead of putting them into functions, and I'd do it by breaking it into pieces. For example, `data[[i, k]] data[[j, m]]` is identical to `data[[j, k]] data[[i, m]]` up to a permutation of indices, so you only have to calculate it once. I'll try and get back to this later today, but that should give you a direction, at least.

Comment: Some general tips based on a quick glance at your code: 1. Try to use vectorization where you can.  Instead of indexing over arrays and processing elements at a time, operate on the whole array.  2. You can use `data /= Norm@Flatten[data]` or `data /= Sqrt@Total[data^2, 2]`  (this is not an answer, just some tips)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your sum can be computed more efficiently as follows:

```
data = Developer`ToPackedArray[data];   
n = Length@data;

f[i_, j_] = Cos[(2 π*(3*10^8)/(1584 - 5 + j*0.1 - 0.05) - 
              2 π*(3*10^8)/(1584 - 5 + i*0.1 - 0.05)) t];

S3[t_] = (Total[data^2, -1]^2 - Total[(data.Transpose[data])^2 Array[f, {n, n}], -1])/2;

ListPlot[Table[S3[i], {i, -0.01, 0.01, 0.0001}], Joined -> True, 
  PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

The total time is about 1 second. Note that the term `Total[data^2, -1]^2` is actually equal to 1 for your data, because of the normalisation.

### How it works

The first term of the sum looks like:

$$\sum _{i,j,k,m} {\left(d_{ik} d_{jm}\right)}^2$$

Since the square of a product is the product of the squares, this can be written as

$$\sum _{i,j,k,m} a_{ik} a_{jm}$$

where $a=d^2$. This takes the product of every possible pair of elements in $a$ and sums them, which is equivalent to summing all the elements of $a$ and then squaring the result. So this gives us

$${\left(\sum _{i,k} a_{ik}\right)}^2$$

The second term is exactly the same (it's just an interchange of indices). So the first two terms of the sum are given by `2 Total[data^2, -1]^2`.

The third term looks like (ignoring the factor of -2):

$$\sum _{i,j,k,m} f_{ij} \left(d_{ik} d_{jk}\right) \left(d_{im} d_{jm}\right)$$

where the cosine term has been expressed as $f_{ij}$. I have also re-ordered the terms to collect the $k$ and $m$ indices together. Again, we have a sum of products which can be expressed as the square of the sum:

$$\sum _{i,j} f_{ij} {\left(\sum _k d_{ik} d_{jk}\right)}^2$$

If we express the term $d_{jk}$ as $(d^T)_{kj}$ we get

$$\sum _{i,j} f_{ij} {\left(\sum _k d_{ik} (d^T)_{kj}\right)}^2$$

where the sum over $k$ is now just an inner product, so we have

$$\sum _{i,j} f_{ij} {\left((d.d^T)^2\right)}_{ij}$$

So the third term of your sum is given by `-2 Total[(data.Transpose[data])^2 Array[f,{n,n}], -1]`

Expressing the sum as I have done makes us of the `Listable` attribute of `Power` and `Times`, and the very fast implementation of `Dot` for numerical arrays. As Szabolcs commented, you will generally get much better performance by acting on a whole array at once instead of on each element individually.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! It works well. But I don't understand why the 4-variable sum can be replaced by `Outer[Dot, data, data, 1]^2 Array[f, {n, n}]`.
Why can't the 4-variable sum cannot be replaced by `data^4 Array[f, {n, n}]`?

Comment: @user14634, I added some explanation.

Comment: Now I can understand this detailed explanation. Thank you so much for your kind help.

Comment: @ Simon Woods, Dear Simon, Thank you very much for your previous help. Now I meet a similar problem related to this one. Would you please teach me how to simplify the equations here [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92285/how-to-simplify-the-equation-and-speed-up-the-codes-for-four-100100-matrices). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Would you please teach me how to simplify the equations here [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92285/how-to-simplify-the-equation-and-speed-up-the-codes-for-four-100100-matrices). Thanks a lot!