# How can I speed up this code？

Tags: summation

There are 4 variables in this multiple sum, and only 2 are used. This question has the similar  scenario as the previous one [How can I speed up this code with multiple sum？](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48640/how-can-i-speed-up-this-code-with-multiple-sum), but the calculation process is different. 
  This code takes about 1 min 38 sec to obtain the results, but I hope the time can be shortened to several seconds.    Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated!

the code is bellow :

```
data = Table[Exp[-((i + j - 50.)/5)^2] Exp[-((i - j)/5)^2], {i, 50}, {j, 50}];
data = Chop[data, 0.00001];
data = data/Sqrt[Sum[(data[[i, j]])^2, {i, 1, 50}, {j, 1, 50}]];
ListDensityPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0, Mesh -> All,  PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Hue[2/3], Hue[0]}, #] &)]


S1[i_, j_, k_, m_, t_] := (data[[i, k]] data[[j, m]])^2 + (data[[j, k]] data[[i, 
  m]])^2 - 2 data[[i, k]] data[[j, m]] data[[j, k]] data[[i, 
 m]] Cos[(2 \[Pi]*(3*10^8)/(1584 - 5 + j*0.1 - 0.05) - 
    2 \[Pi]*(3*10^8)/(1584 - 5 + i*0.1 - 0.05)) t];
S2[i_, j_, t_] := 1/4*\!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k = 1\), \(50\)]\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(m = 1\), \(50\)]S1[i, j, k, m, 
  t]\)\);
data2 = Table[S2[i, j, 4*0.001], {i, 1, 50}, {j, 1, 50}];
ListDensityPlot[data2, InterpolationOrder -> 0, Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Hue[2/3], Hue[0]}, #] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: Look into Compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have read [Simon Woods's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48654/1871) more carefully. The difference between this question and the previous one is just you don't need to sum over $j$ and $k$ now, with almost same analysis, you can figure out that `data2` is equal to

$$ 2 {\left((d.d^T)^2\right)}_{ij}(1 - f_{ij})/4$$

So here is the code:

```
a = AbsoluteTiming;
data0 = Table[Exp[-((i + j - 50.)/5)^2] Exp[-((i - j)/5)^2], {i, 50}, {j, 50}];
data = Partition[Normalize@Flatten@Chop[data0, 0.00001], 50]; // a
ArrayPlot[data, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Black, 
                ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Hue[2/3], Hue[0]}, #] &)] // a
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice my modification for `data`. (As mentioned by Simon in the previous post, *you will generally get much better performance by acting on a whole array at once instead of on each element individually.*) Also, I chose `ArrayPlot` instead of `ListDensityPlot` because it's faster and has the same effect as your `ListDensityPlot`  with the option `InterpolatingOrder -> 0`.

The rest part is nearly the same as Simon's:

```
f[i_, j_, t_] = Cos[(2 Pi (3 10^8)/(1584 - 5 + 0.1 j - 0.05) - 
                2 Pi (3 10^8)/(1584 - 5 + 0.1 i - 0.05)) t];
data2 = 2 (data.Transpose[data])^2 (1 - Array[f[##, 4 0.001] &, {50, 50}]) / 4; // a
ArrayPlot[data2, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Black, 
                 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Hue[2/3], Hue[0]}, #1] &)] // a
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @xzczd  Thank you so much! Your answer is really helpful.

Comment: @blochwave, thank you for your kind encouragement.

Comment: @xzczd  How to prove the first term? I mean
sum\limits_ {k, m} (d_ {ik} d_ {jm})^2 = (d_. d^T)^2 _ {ij} ?                                                      Can we prove:  sum\limits_ {k, m} (d_ {ik} d_ {jm})^2 =sum\limits_ {k, k} (d_ {ik} d_ {jk})^2 ? It seems difficult.

Comment: @user14634 This is exactly what Simon proves in the last 4 steps of his explanation. By the way, the justification can be even easier with [tensor notation](http://www.continuummechanics.org/cm/tensornotationbasic.html).

Answer (score 2):

Like Ajasja said in a comment, `Compile` is your best friend here (short of completely rewriting `S1` and `S2` like in your other question). Simply compiling everything together:

```
With[{d = data},
  S2 = Compile[
    {{i, _Integer}, {j, _Integer}, {t, _Real}},
     1/4*Sum[
      (d[[i, k]] d[[j, m]])^2 
       + (d[[j, k]] d[[i, m]])^2 
       - 2 d[[i, k]] d[[j, m]] d[[j, k]] d[[i, m]] Cos[
         (2 \[Pi]*(3*10^8)/(1584 - 5 + j*0.1 - 0.05) - 
            2 \[Pi]*(3*10^8)/(1584 - 5 + i*0.1 - 0.05)) t
         ],
      {k, 1, 50}, {m, 1, 50}
      ],
    CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ]
  ];
```

gives a considerably speed increase:

```
(data2 = Table[S2[i, j, 4*0.001], {i, 1, 50}, {j, 1, 50}];) // Timing
```

> {0.915097, Null}

Note that inserting `data` into the compiled function with `With` is key to getting a big speed increase. My guess is that the compiled function then doesn't have to go to the main evaluation loop to acces `data` each time, which would severely slow performance.

Comment: Many thanks to Teake Nutma and Ajasja. The Compile function works well.

Comment: You're welcome, but @xzczd's answer is a whole lot better :).

Comment: @ Teake Nutma, I met the error of "A C compiler cannot be found on your system. Please consult the documentation to learn how to set up suitable compilers." Should I install some compilers first?

Comment: @user14634 That shouldn't be necessary. What Mathematica version are you on? The options to Compile I gave (CompilationTarget, RuntimeOptions) only work for Mathematica 8 or newer; if you have 7 or older you can simply omit them. Note that doing so on Mathematica 7 will slow down performance to around 10 seconds.

Comment: I am using Mathematica 8.0; The Compile function can be used, but the warnings appear.

Comment: @user14634 Turns out I was wrong: depending on your system you'll need to install compilers. If you're on OS X [this might help](http://comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica.narkive.com/RGhDpP8u/mac-new-os-mountain-lion-compile-function-c-compiler-vrs-8-0-4).

Comment: @ Teake Nutma, I am using a Windows 7 system.

Comment: @user14634 Then your best bet would be to install [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vc/).

Comment: @ Teake Nutma, Thank you for the information.